# nginx - URL encode query string

Tags: regex, nginx, urlencode

I have an nginx reverse-proxy which needs to pass on the query string it receives. However this query string it receives is not well formatted and can contain JSON that is not URL encoded i.e. it contains curly brackets i.e. {}, commas, colons and double quotes! Unfortunately, I have no control over this and this causes the downstream server to barf when parsing the string.

Is there a way to correctly URL encode this string before proxying it?

I can replace the curly brackets as I know there will only be one instance of each using the config:

```
if ($args ~* '(.*){(.*)}(.*)') {
    set $args $1%7B$2%7D$3;
    rewrite (.*)$ $1;
}
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

However, I don't know in advance how many fields the JSON will have so it's difficult to use the same logic as above for the rest of the object.

I should also mention that I don't think this is related to nginx url-decoding parameters as I am not using a URI in the proxy_pass.

Thanks!

UPDATE: For the time being, the JSON object seems to be sending the same properties so this is what I've used as a workaround. It's pretty hideous and will break if the number of properties changes but does the job for now.

```
if ($args ~* '(.*){"(.*)":"(.*)","(.*)":"(.*)","(.*)":"(.*)","(.*)":"(.*)","(?<group10>.*)":"(?<group11>.*)"}(?<group12>.*)') {
    set $args $1%7B%22$2%22%3A%22$3%22%2C%22$4%22%3A%22$5%22%2C%22$6%22%3A%22$7%22%2C%22$8%22%3A%22$9%22%2C%22${group10}%22%3A%22${group11}%22%7D${group12};
    rewrite (.*)$ $1;
}
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

Note that since this returns more than 9 regex groups, I had to name groups 10, 11 and 12 otherwise they get interpreted as $1 + the digit 0, 1 or 2.

Is there a more robust way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why is it an issue for your backend to process a URI with the curly braces in it.  Are you sure that's what the actual problem is?

Comment: The backend server uses the dropwizard (http://www.dropwizard.io/) framework - it's this that throws a URISyntaxException when parsing the query string it receives. I'm unable to find a way to catch this as it appears to happen outside of my control. The simplest workaround I could think of was to fix the query string before it reaches the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like a solution with a single `if` statement, because it doesn't look very readable, flexible or maintainable.  You may see whether having a combination of `location` or `rewrite` statements, where each one handles a specific encoding case, may work; see http://mdoc.su/ for a fun project that's very heavy with internal redirects, although I believe at one point nginx may have a limit on the total number of indirections.

Otherwise, provided that you cannot modify the backend, another option is to automatically redirect misbehaving clients and/or requests to an auxiliary backend, whose only purpose is to re-encode the string correctly, providing an `X-Accel-Redirect` HTTP Response Header as its output (as per http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ignore_headers), which nginx will use to make a subsequent internal redirect / request to the actual backend.